# How can ViewPager can switch fragment by vertical scrolling?

Tags: java, android-viewpager, android

I'm working on my first real Android application. 
 And so, i have plenty of information to display in one activity. So i would like have 4 screen that can have vertical scroll to switch to another screen ( like a ViewPager does horizontally).

I haven't found a way to make a ViewPager scroll vertically.

I look up on the net, and here. But i did not find any thread who give a straight answer.

I have even try to switch to Landscape and make all element rotate by 90 degree, but that's really not a good way to do...
So please helps me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make whit swipe, and on each swipe change activity from array, here is a small example of what I have in mind.

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;


 int[] values = new int[] {
    R.layout.Layout1,
    R.layout.Layout2,
    R.layout.Layout3 };

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
    float velocityY) {

try {
    if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * left to right swipe
     */
    if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

         //next Layout
            setContentView(array[]+1)


        /**
         * right to left
         */
    } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
            && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {


            //prev layout
            setContentView(array[]-1)

        }

    }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
return false;
}
```

Hope you will find this usefull, 
Cheers